# Raspberry Pi C++ Read NMEA Sentences from Adafruit's Ultimate GPS Module

Tags: c++, c, gps, raspberry-pi, nmea

I'm trying to read the GPS NMEA sentences from Adafruit's Ultimate GPS module. I'm using C++ on the raspberry pi to read the serial port connection to the module

Here is my read function:

```
int Linuxutils::readFromSerialPort(int fd, int bufferSize) {

    /*
    Reading data from a port is a little trickier. When you operate the port in raw data mode,
    each read(2) system call will return however many characters are actually available in the
    serial input buffers. If no characters are available, the call will block (wait) until
    characters come in, an interval timer expires, or an error occurs. The read function can be
    made to return immediately by doing the following:
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    The NDELAY option causes the read function to return 0 if no characters are available on the port.
    */

    // Check the file descriptor
    if ( !checkFileDecriptorIsValid(fd) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from serial port - it is not a valid file descriptor!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Now, let's wait for an input from the serial port.
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0); // block until data comes in

    // Now read the data
    int absoluteMax = bufferSize*2;
    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferSize); // allocate buffer.
    int rcount = 0;
    int length = 0;

    // Read in each newline
    FILE* fdF = fdopen(fd, "r");
    int ch = getc(fdF);
    while ( (ch != '\n') ) { // Check for end of file or newline

        // Reached end of file
        if ( ch == EOF ) {
            printf("ERROR: EOF!");
            continue;
        }

        // Expand by reallocating if necessary
        if( rcount == absoluteMax ) { // time to expand ?
          absoluteMax *= 2; // expand to double the current size of anything similar.
          rcount = 0; // Re-init count
          buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, absoluteMax); // Re-allocate memory.
        }

        // Read from stream
        ch = getc(fdF);

        // Stuff in buffer
        buffer[length] = ch;

        // Increment counters
        length++;
        rcount++;

    }

    // Don't care if we return 0 chars read
    if ( rcount == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Stick
    buffer[rcount] = '\0';

    // Print results
    printf("Received ( %d bytes ): %s\n", rcount,buffer);

    // Return bytes read
    return rcount;

}
```

So I kind of get the sentences as you can see below, the problem is I get these "repeated" portions of a complete sentence like this:

```
Received ( 15 bytes ): M,-31.4,M,,*61
```

Here is the complete thing:

```
Received ( 72 bytes ): GPGGA,182452.000,4456.2019,N,09337.0243,W,1,8,1.19,292.6,M,-31.4,M,,*61

Received ( 56 bytes ): GPGSA,A,3,17,07,28,26,08,11,01,09,,,,,1.49,1.19,0.91*00

Received ( 15 bytes ): M,-31.4,M,,*61

Received ( 72 bytes ): GPGGA,182453.000,4456.2019,N,09337.0242,W,1,8,1.19,292.6,M,-31.4,M,,*61

Received ( 56 bytes ): GPGSA,A,3,17,07,28,26,08,11,01,09,,,,,1.49,1.19,0.91*00

Received ( 15 bytes ): M,-31.4,M,,*61

Received ( 72 bytes ): GPGGA,182456.000,4456.2022,N,09337.0241,W,1,8,1.21,292.6,M,-31.4,M,,*64

Received ( 56 bytes ): GPGSA,A,3,17,07,28,26,08,11,01,09,,,,,2.45,1.21,2.13*0C

Received ( 70 bytes ): GPRMC,182456.000,A,4456.2022,N,09337.0241,W,0.40,183.74,110813,,,A*7F

Received ( 37 bytes ): GPVTG,183.74,T,,M,0.40,N,0.73,K,A*34

Received ( 70 bytes ): GPRMC,182453.000,A,4456.2019,N,09337.0242,W,0.29,183.74,110813,,,A*7E

Received ( 37 bytes ): GPVTG,183.74,T,,M,0.29,N,0.55,K,A*3F

Received ( 32 bytes ): 242,W,0.29,183.74,110813,,,A*7E

Received ( 70 bytes ): GPRMC,182452.000,A,4456.2019,N,09337.0243,W,0.33,183.74,110813,,,A*75
```

Why am I getting the repeated sentences and how can I fix it? I tried flushing the serial port buffers but then things became really ugly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your exact problem.  There are a few problems with the function though which might explain a variety of errors.

The lines

```
int absoluteMax = bufferSize*2;
char *buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferSize); // allocate buffer.
```

seem wrong.  You'll decide when to grow the buffer by comparing the number of characters read to `absoluteMax` so this needs to match the size of the buffer allocated.  You're currently writing beyond the end of allocated memory before you reallocate.  This results in undefined behaviour.  If you're lucky your app will crash, if you're unlucky, things will appear to work but you'll lose the second half of the data you've read since only the data written to memory you own will be moved by `realloc` (if it relocates your heap cell).

Also, you shouldn't cast the return from `malloc` (or `realloc`) and can rely on `sizeof(char)` being 1.

You lose the first character read (the one that is read just before the `while` loop).  Is this deliberate?

When you reallocate `buffer`, you shouldn't reset `rcount`.  This causes the same bug as above where you'll write beyond the end of `buffer` before reallocating again.  Again, the effects of doing this are undefined but could include losing portions of output.

Not related to the bug you're currently concerned with but also worth noting is the fact that you leak `buffer` and `fdF`.  You should `free` and `fclose` them respectively before exiting the function.

The following (untested) version ought to fix these issues

```
int Linuxutils::readFromSerialPort(int fd, int bufferSize)
{
    if ( !checkFileDecriptorIsValid(fd) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from serial port - it is not a valid file descriptor!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0); // block until data comes in
    int absoluteMax = bufferSize;
    char *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    int rcount = 0;
    int length = 0;

    // Read in each newline
    FILE* fdF = fdopen(fd, "r");
    int ch = getc(fdF);
    for (;;) {
        int ch = getc(fdF);
        if (ch == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        if (ch == EOF) { // Reached end of file
            printf("ERROR: EOF!\n");
            break;
        }
        if (length+1 >= absoluteMax) {
            absoluteMax *= 2;
            char* tmp = realloc(buffer, absoluteMax);
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR: OOM\n");
                goto cleanup;
            }
            buffer = tmp;
        }
        buffer[length++] = ch;
    }

    if (length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    buffer[length] = '\0';

    // Print results
    printf("Received ( %d bytes ): %s\n", rcount,buffer);

cleanup:
    free(buffer);
    fclose(fdH);
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to flush serial port buffers before reading from it as shown [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013387/clearing-the-serial-ports-buffer) ?

I would also consider not reopening the serial port every time you call Linuxutils::readFromSerialPort - you could keep the file descriptor open for further reading (anyway the call is blocking so from the caller's point of view nothing changes).